# Trying to get the largest number in a column of a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

This is what I have currently, I get the error int is 'int' object is not iterable. If I understand correctly my issue is that BIKE_AVAILABLE is assigned a number at the top of my project with a number so instead of looking at the column it is looking at that number and hitting an error. How should I go about going through the column? I apologize in advance for the newby question

```
for i in range(len(stations[BIKES_AVAILABLE]) -1):
    most_bikes = max(stations[BIKES_AVAILABLE])
sort(stations[BIKES_AVAILABLE]).remove(max(stations[BIKES_AVAILABLE]))

if most_bikes == max(stations[BIKES_AVAILABLE]):
    second_most = max(stations[BIKES_AVAILABLE])
    index_1 = index(most_bikes)
    index_2 = index(second_most)
    most_bikes = max(data[0][index_1], data[0][index_2])

return most_bikes
```

Comment: What is the data structure of `stations`?

Comment: Daniel, welcome to SO! Your code example is not complete, one cannot run it as such and reproduce your problem. Have a look at [how to write a minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use a pandas DataFrame. Pandas can directly read csv files into a DataFrame. Dataframes allow for min/max etc.

Comment: As an aside, are you sure you want `for i in range(len(stations[BIKES_AVAILABLE]) -1)` rather than `for i in range(len(stations[BIKES_AVAILABLE]))` ? As an example, `for i in range(3)` will loop through i with values of `0`, `1`, `2` - but *not* `3`... It goes up to, but does not include the numbered value.  This  makes `for i in range(len(somelist))` the more common pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using a `generator` inside `max()`

If you have a `CSV` file named `test.csv`, with contents:

```
line1,3,abc
line2,1,ahc
line3,9,sbc
line4,4,agc
```

You can use a `generator` `expression` inside the `max()` `function` for a `memory` efficient solution (i.e. no `list` is created).

If you wanted to do this for the second `column`, then:

```
max(int(l.split(',')[1]) for l in open("test.csv").readlines())
```

which would give `9` for this example.

---

**Update**

To get the `row` (`index`), you need to store the `index` of the `max` number in the `column` so that you can access this:

```
max(((i,int(l.split(',')[1])) for i,l in enumerate(open("test.csv").readlines())),key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
```

which gives `2` here as the `line` in `test.csv` (above) with the `max` number in `column` `2` (which is `9`) is `2` (i.e. the third line).

This works fine, but you may prefer to just break it up slightly:

```
lines = open("test.csv").readlines()
max(((i,int(l.split(',')[1])) for i,l in enumerate(lines)),key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and if i wanted to find the index of that number could I do this  index_of_max = [BIKES_AVAILABLE].index(max(int(l.split(',')[BIKES_AVAILABLE]) for l in open("stations.csv").readlines()))

Comment: @DanielLynes No, not quite as I assume `BIKES_AVAILABLE` as the `column` (?) so you would then be trying to do `.index` on an `integer` which just wouldn't work. I have updated my answer with how to get the `row` properly...

Comment: Please remember to `accept` and `up-vote` if this works fine for you as well!

Answer (score 2):

Another method that might be better for you to use with data manipulation is to try the `pandas` module.

Then you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('bicycle_data.csv')

# Alternative:
# most_sales = data['sold'].max()
most_sales = max(data['sold'])
```

Now you don't have to worry about indexing columns with numbers:

You can also do something like this:

```
sorted_data = data.sort_values(by='sold', ascending=False)

# Displays top 5 sold bicycles.
print(sorted_data.head(5))
```

More importantly if you enjoy using indexes, there is a function to get you the index of the `max` value called [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) built into `pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a csv structure like so:

```
data = ['1,blue,15,True',
    '2,red,25,False',
    '3,orange,35,False',
    '4,yellow,24,True',
    '5,green,12,True']
```

If I want to get the max value from the 3rd column I would do this:

```
largest_number = max([n.split(',')[2] for n in data])
```